# hg: fix branching without merges

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have repository with wrong branching. Branches was used like tag for commit message, showing related  part of project (eg data, search - like features). No merging was used. Each next commit, if it is about other feature than prev, just reopens branch with desired name.

It looks like

```
o changeset:   717
| branch:      default
|
o changeset:   523
| branch:      search
|
o changeset:   357
| branch:      data
|
o changeset:   397
| branch:      data
|
o changeset:   789
| branch:      default
```

Whats the right way to stop that ugliness?

Update to each branch-head and merge with last commit consequentially? But there nothing to merge actually. 
Or update to each head, commit with "close branch", update to next head ... and at last update to default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as Aaron pointed out, and assuming these are misunderstandings by the commiters, you will need to teach the others working on that repo when its appropriate ( by your definition of appropriate ) to create named branches, and when it isn't. I imagine that would solve most of your problems.

If you want to bring everything back in line, and the branches are currently open, you can close each branch and then merge them into default. If you don't merge after closing, you will have a 'dangling' commit in your history graph, but that may or may not matter to you. Also, if you only have 1 'active' branch, which you can check with

> hg branches

then all the commits are currently merged into that active branch, and you may only need to merge that branch into default to bring things in line. However you may still want to close the inactive branches, which will leave you with dangling commits if you don't merge them after closing.

If you want to avoid having commits with branchnames, you could look at using [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks), which are sort of an amalgamation of branching and tagging.

If you want to minimise branching ( even anonymous branching ) on your repo, you could use [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), which is a built in extension that you have to enable. You can use the rebase switch when pulling someone else's changes, to automatically move your commits after the commits you are pulling in and make the history linear. You cannot do this once your commits have already been pulled or pushed elsewhere however ( well, you [could](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases), but it would make things very complicated depending on what happens with your pulled commits ). However using rebase would depend on how you feel about keeping accurate history.

To clean up the existing repo could be a bit of a mission. You could use rebase to move all the commits to a common branch, such as default, however since it changes your history it will no longer be 'compatible' with the existing clones of that repo. So you would have to use rebase to alter your history, and then have everyone ( including servers ) reclone the altered repo and trash the old one ( they cannot even pull any outstand commits from the old one to the altered repo ).

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the history (just one line), people really just gave each commit a different branch name without actually ever doing any work on two different branches at the same time.

While I haven't seen this before, it's a interesting and clean way to sort changesets into features without creating an ugly history.

As for "stopping" this, just stop reopen branches. There is nothing that you need to do to "clean" the history since there aren't actually any heads which need merging. Therefore, Mercurial will tell you "nothing to merge" if you check out `default` and say `hg merge search`.